# Should I start a helper function with underscore(s)?

Tags: python, function, module

In a module, should I use one, two, or no underscores to denote a helper function the user should **not** call?

Comment: Good description of single and double underscores here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PEP-8, the Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), suggests a single leading underscore.

> The following special forms using leading or trailing underscores are recognized (these can generally be combined with any case convention):
>
> - `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.
> - ...

Answer (score 2):

Probably a single underscore, but it depends on the situation.

Specifically, the Python Style Guide (PEP 8) says:

> _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.
>
> __double_leading_underscore: when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class FooBar, __boo becomes _FooBar__boo; see below).

See also this question for some much longer answers:
[What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Comment: What particularly does double underscore do in a module? Anything different from single underscore?

Comment: Yes, when it's part of a class - it triggers name mangling.  See the docs for a full explanation:  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Comment: Broadly speaking, you use it mostly to prevent subclasses from trivially overriding the method.